# cannot load such file -- systemu error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have updated sidekiq gem to the latest version. Now I am getting the following error when I try to run the server:

```
cannot load such file -- systemu
/home/kiprosh22/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@liquor/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/kiprosh22/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@liquor/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/kiprosh22/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@liquor/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/kiprosh22/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@liquor/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/kiprosh22/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@liquor/gems/macaddr-1.6.2/lib/macaddr.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
......
```

I am unable to find the cause for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue this morning after running `bundle update`.

Adding

`gem macaddr, '1.6.1'`

to the *Gemfile* and running `bundle update macaddr` cleared it for now.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the latest version of the `systemu` gem has an [dependency issue](https://github.com/ahoward/macaddr/issues/2) (see last comment), which is caused by the [latest commit](https://github.com/ahoward/macaddr/commit/a0ae1a76775c705206bde51772d53b178be5ce45) (see the comments that others have added).